# Is it possible to build a Progressive Web App without client side rendering?

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps

My company's site is mostly server rendered (we make some use of [Structured Page Fragments](https://github.com/youtube/spfjs)) but we'd like to look into building a Progressive Web App.

Does it make sense to build a Progressive Web App by implementing service worker caching for server rendered pages? Alternatively, should we rather explore moving to client side rendering?

Note that we'd like to do as much rendering as we can on the server as we support many very slow devices.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, service workers are definitely not restricted to client side rendering.

You can cache whatever you want. For example, [this WordPress plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/offline-content/) caches WordPress content.

Answer (score 2):

Server-rendered pages imply that there is some degree of dynamic or personalized content on your site—otherwise, you'd just be serving static HTML.

I'd encourage you to initially think about it from the perspective of how you want to deal with your dynamic content, both when you're online and offline. Reading through Jake Archibald's [Offline Cookbook](https://jakearchibald.com/2014/offline-cookbook/) will give you a good overview of the different strategies that could be implemented.

Once you're set on a caching strategy for your dynamic content, the next step is to implement it. The "gold standard" approach is to use an [App Shell + dynamic content architecture](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/11/app-shell?hl=en), but it can take some refactoring to get an existing application onto this architecture, especially one where the initial HTML returned by the server contains dynamic/personalized elements.

If refactoring is too daunting a task, or if server-only rendering is a hard-requirement, then you can still make use of service worker caching, but you'll probably end up treating your would-be shell as if it were dynamic content. This means a pure cache-first strategy might not be "safe", but a [cache/network race](https://jakearchibald.com/2014/offline-cookbook/#cache-network-race) might work, or at least [network, falling back to cache](https://jakearchibald.com/2014/offline-cookbook/#network-falling-back-to-cache).

Using both of those strategies, you'd end up with a web app that would work offline, but you'll likely end up caching duplicated data (i.e. if `/page1` and `/page2` share some common HTML structure, you'd end up caching that twice). You'd also take a performance and bandwidth-consumption hit since you'd have to go to the network more often than you would with an App Shell, but that could be mitigated somewhat via proper HTTP browser caching headers. (Which you should think about anyway, for browsers that lack service worker support.)

Comment: From a performance perspective, what is faster and more efficient for the client? A progressive web app with a cached app shell using a solely JavaScipt front-end with client side rendering or server side rendering with 'Cache & network race'? Also, if you were to use server side rendering with 'Cache & network race' you could end up with a *lot* of cached pages and many pages not cached at all, what is the solution here?

Comment: "It depends." But see https://jeffy.info/2017/01/24/offline-first-for-your-templated-site-part-2.html